# Code analysis rule CA1040: Avoid empty interfaces, complains on a non empty interface

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-analysis, fxcop

I have an interface that declares events

```
interface IMyInterface
{
event SomeHandler MyEvent1;
event SomeHandler MyEvent2;
...
}
```

but when I enable the Code analysis rule *CA1040: Avoid empty interfaces*, it complains that my interface violates this rule, any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Just suppress the warning? It's clearly spurious.

Comment: I prefer to suppress only when I have a real reason, in this case the reason would be that the rule does not work properly

Comment: Strange if it considers the interface to be empty. The `event` declaration is a requirement that the implementing class/struct must have en `event` with that type (`SomeHandler`) containing both `add` and `remove` accessors. The two accessors can be "implicit" if the implementer chooses to use a "field-like event". Does it work with indexers only, i.e. if the only member of `IMyInterface` is `string this[int idx] { get; }`?

Comment: Here's an interface in the BCL that contains only an event (with `add` and `remove` accessors of course): **[`INotifyCollectionChanged` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Collections.Specialized.INotifyCollectionChanged.aspx)**

Comment: I cannot reproduct the problem.  Which version of Visual Studio are you running?

Comment: vs 2010, pay attention that the rule is enabled and on error

Comment: I cannot repro in VS 2010 using the code above, even after making the interface public (which is necessary to trigger CA1040 in general).  Could you please provide a full example (including definition of SomeHandler) that actually results in a CA1040 violation?

Answer (score 2):

<strike>The reason why it complains, is because *this* interface does not requires any implamentation.
You cannot implement an event declaration in any specific way.</strike>

As Matthew suggest, just suppress it. you might need to add this in the top of you class:

```
#define CODE_ANALYSIS
```

or the suppresion is ignored.

**Edit**

It might be a bug after all, as any classes that inherit the interface is infact requeried to "implement" it - hence : it is *not* an empty interface.

Comment: You say "this interface does not requires any implamentation" - but `class Foo : IMyInterface { }` fails to compile!

Comment: tuche - it does. that is somewhat supprising as there only can be one implementation of those events. edit my answer.

Comment: Not just one implementation of the events: could be `event SomeHandler MyEvent1;`, or `event SomeHandler Event1 { add { ... } remove { ... } }`.

Answer (score 0):

See this article. It describes how to use the `SuppressMessageAttribute`. Visual Studio provides a convenient menu to add this attribute:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182069.aspx